# I'm puzzled with 0.99999

Tags: decimal-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does .99999… = 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1)

After reading all the kind answers for [this previous question question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29638/how-do-we-find-a-fraction-with-whose-decimal-expansion-has-a-given-repeating-patt),
I wonder... How do we get a fraction whose decimal expansion is the simple $0.\overline{9}$?

I don't mean to look like kidding or joking (of course, one can teach math with fun so it becomes more interesting), but this series has really raised a flag here, because $\frac{9}{9}$ won't solve this case, although it solves for all other digits (e.g. $0.\overline{8}=\frac{8}{9}$ and so on).

Thanks!
Beco.

Comment: Since $0.\overline 9=1$, $\tfrac99$ *does* solve this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create." Is your question answered by the discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1 ?

Comment: $0.9999... = 1$. You can create it with $1/1=1$. This is a duplicate of many questions, or if that information is not enough, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: @Qiaochu: The OP just recently asked how, given a repeating decimal, get a fraction that has *that* decimal expansion. The title was not very felicitous, though.

Comment: Hum... It looks like it is one of those corners of mathematics. If some mod feel it should close this question, please do so. Thanks your patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number $0.9999\cdots$ is in fact equal to $1$, which is why you get $\frac{9}{9}$. See [this previous question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1)

To see it is equal to $1$, you can use any number of ideas:

1. The *hand-wavy but convincing one*: Let $x=0.999\cdots$. Then $10x = 9.999\cdots = 9 + x$. So $9x = 9$, hence $x=1$.
2. The **formal one.** The decimal expansion describes an infinite series. Here we have that
   $$ x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^n}.$$
   This is a geometric series with common ration $\frac{1}{10}$ and initial term $\frac{9}{10}$, so
   $$x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^n} = \frac{\quad\frac{9}{10}}{1 - \frac{1}{10}} = \frac{\frac{9}{10}}{\quad\frac{9}{10}\quad} = 1.$$

In general, a number whose decimal expansion *terminates* (has a "tail of 0s") always has **two** decimal expansions, one with a tail of 9s. So:
$$\begin{align*}
1.0000\cdots &= 0.9999\cdots\\
2.480000\cdots &= 2.4799999\cdots\\
1938.01936180000\cdots &= 1938.019361799999\cdots
\end{align*}$$
etc.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept the answer right now. Only in 6 minutes according with the site. I'll do it soon.